# Referring to a Hierarchy of Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, hierarchy

I come from a Java background and want to refer to things in a similar way.
I’m not sure where to look.
 **pseudo code:**

```
var elements = [];

class Element
{
   constructor()
              {
              this.isClicked;
              }
   mouseOver()
              {
              ///returns true if mouse is over
              }
   click()
              {
              this.isClicked = true;
              }
   unclick()
              {
              this.isClicked = false;
              }

}

class Parent extends Element 
{

   constructor()
              {
              this.children = [];
              this.x = 0;
              this.y = 0;
              elements.push(this)
              }
   addChild()
              {
              children.push(new Child(this));
              }
}

class Child extends Element
{
   constructor(Parent p)
              {
              this.parent = p;
              this.x = 0;
              this.y = 0;
              elements.push(this)
              }

   move()
              {
              this.x = parent.x;
              this.y = parent.y;
              }
}

var liveElement;

function mousePressed()
{
    for(Element e : elements)
              {
              if(e.mouseOver)
                        {
                        liveElement = e;
                        liveElement.click();
                        }
              }
}

function mouseReleased()
{
    liveElement.unclick();
    liveElement = null;
}
```

Is it possible to do this kind of thing in vanilla JavaScript? I would also like to refer to all the objects horizontally in `elements`. The Child objects should be able to refer up to `parent` when needed.

Comment: Check out typescript:https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Drop the type annotations and you mostly got valid JS.

Comment: Your hierarchy is really problematic. A child cannot be a parent itself, so this is inappropriate for a tree.

Comment: @Bergi Do you suggest that I wrap them together into the `Elements` class and do away with `Parent` and `Child`?

Comment: @jackoverflow Probably, although I have no idea what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do things somehow similar in JS since ES2015 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). In case the app should run in different browsers and versions I would recommend you to use a compiler such Babel (https://babeljs.io/) bacause last ES features are not compatible with older browsers. Relations between child and parent classes could be found in mdn reference (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super). Hope it helps.